# How to extend the line drawn using CGMutablePathRef in both direction?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am drawing line using

```
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();

for (int i = 0; i < [_points count]; i++)
{
    CGPoint pt = [[_points objectAtIndex:i] CGPointValue];
    if (i == 0)
    {
        CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, pt.x+1, pt.y+1);
    }
    else
    {
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, pt.x+1, pt.y+1);
    }
}

CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0f);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, curveColor.CGColor);
CGContextAddPath(context, path);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
CGPathRelease(path);
```

I can extent the line in one direction. But i want to extend the line in both direction (upside and downside) to certain extent. How to extend the line in Both direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At finally got the answer with the help of @Wain comment,

```
- (NSArray *)lineDrawingPoints:(CGFloat)slope pointX1:(CGFloat)ptX1 pointY1:(CGFloat)ptY1 maxValX:(CGFloat)biggestNumberX maxValY:(CGFloat)biggestNumberY {

    NSMutableArray *infiniteLinePoints = [NSMutableArray array];
    float y;

    for(int x = -biggestNumberX ; x <= biggestNumberX ; x++ ){
        y = slope * (x - ptX1)+ptY1;
        if(y >= -biggestNumberY && y <= biggestNumberY )
           [infiniteLinePoints addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(x, y)]];
    }

    return infiniteLinePoints;
}
```

Thanks Wain.

Answer (score 1):

To extend one end:

```
[_points insertObject:newStartPoint atIndex:0];
```

and the other:

```
[_points addObject:newEndPoint];
```

Comment: i am unable to find the newStartPoint and newEndPoint... So i want to extend recursively until the point reaches certain limit..How to do that?